# Header issues if page length exceeds certain size

Tags: http, nginx, web2py, http-1.1, http-1.0

This is regarding the website http://zumbl.com. We realized today that the pages are not being served at some places. On doing some experiments, we further realized that the pages with small output size are being displayed ok, but if we increase the size of the content to be served then the receiving browser complains of header issues. We are using nginx and web2py. Any ideas what can be the potential problem?

Can the problem be because of HTTP 1.0 vs. 1.1 headers?

As realized the problem isn't specific to http protocol but works so on each protocol. I created a new question as the description is quite different for both these scenarios. ([Packets of length 1400 not being received from a specific server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812137/packets-of-length-1400-not-being-received-from-a-specific-server))

Comment: "the receiving browser complains of header issues" Care to elaborate?

Comment: It says - "Following server is down. Couldn't read headers." Most of the time though it keeps on loading and nothing happens, and sometimes this error message comes up.

Comment: I see a `X-Page-Speed` header in your responses. Are you using the ngx page speed module?

Comment: I'd try with regular nginx for a while. Not sure that's the culprit, but it's a good chance.

Comment: We tried, but the same issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43364/discussion-between-w2lame-and-dasourcerer)